# Question about using simple html dom parser to store HTML tags as objects

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am building a web scraper using the simple HTML DOM parser. However, I ran into some issues figuring out how to store HTML elements on a web page as objects. I would like to take an input URL, and turn all the HTML elements like tags, divs, fields, etc. and turn them into an object that gets spit out onto a page. I have written some code that currently works when I type in a URL, but the output is not what I am trying to achieve. Below, I have attached the code that I have worked out already, and I am seeking to find a way in which I could achieve what I am trying to do.

I have tried finding all images and links as well as creating a DOM object. I can't seem to figure out how to convert these elements into objects that I can use to learn more about a website, and possibly store that data into a database.

```
<?php
require('simple_html_dom.php');

    // Create DOM from URL or file
    $url = $_POST["url"];
    $html = file_get_html($url);
    echo $html;
    // Find all images
    $element = new simple_html_dom();
    foreach($html->find('img') as $element)
           echo $element->src . '<br>';

    // Find all links
    $element = new simple_html_dom();
    foreach($html->find('a') as $element)
           echo $element->href . '<br>';

    // Create a DOM object
    $html = new simple_html_dom();

    // Load HTML from a URL
    $html->load_file($url);
    echo $html;
?>
```

I am expecting an output of objects, but I am instead getting an actual output of images and links on a web page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

require('simple_html_dom.php');

// Create DOM from URL or file
// $url = $_POST["url"];

$url = 'Your-Url'; // Your url: 'www.example.com'
$html = file_get_html($url);

// Find all images
$images = []; //create empty images array
foreach($html->find('img') as $element){

    $images[] = $element->src . '<br>'; //Store the found elements in the images array
}

echo '<pre>Output $images: '; var_dump($images); echo '</pre>'; //An output from the images array

// Find all links
$links = []; //create empty images array
foreach($html->find('a') as $element){

    $links[] =  $element->href . '<br>'; //Store the found elements in the links array
}

echo '<pre>Output $links: '; var_dump($links); echo '</pre>'; //An output from the links array
```

The echo's display the arrays filled with 'image' and 'a' tags value's from your page